# Calling a phone using UIWebview

Tags: uiwebview

I am calling a phone using UIWebview which is giving me a alert with "Cancel" and "Call" I want to handle the "Call" and "Cancel" Btns, if i press "Call" i am able to call and if i dismiss the call it is coming back to my application, please help me in handling the "Call" and "Cancel" Btns

```
UIWebview  *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen Screen].applicationFrame];

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",newNumber]]]];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/24098-uialertview-button-trigger-events.html

Comment: i dont have any alert view, its the web view  which is showing me alert box with "call" and "cancel" btn

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behavior of the application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[number stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

or

```
UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

see the difference.